# How to change the property of UILabels which store in a NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

i am going to just add one UILabel into array as example

```
NSMutablearray *labels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,20,20)];
newLabel.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
[labels addObject:newLabel];
```

then later i want to change newLabel.center by doing something like this

```
[labels objectAtIndex:1].center.x +=10;
```

this gives me an error "request for member "center" in something not a structure or union"
then i try

```
    [labels objectAtIndex:1]->center.x +=10;
```

then this gives me another error said struct objc_object has no member named 'center'

how can i change the property of UILabel that is store in NSMutableArray?

Comment: An nsarray is 0-based, so the first object in it has an index of 0, not 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting this error because the return type of `objectAtIndex:` is simply `id` (which can be any object); NSArray is a generic container, when you retrieve an object from it, there's no way to know what type it is. **You** know, because you put the objects in it, but the compiler doesn't know.

You wrote:

```
[labels objectAtIndex:1].center.x +=10;
```

That's technically correct, but the compiler can't type check it. It's equivalent to writing this:

```
id object = [labels objectAtIndex:1];
object.center.x +=10;
```

The second line is where the error occurs: the compiler knows `object` is an Objective-C object, but it doesn't know what class, so it doesn't know what properties have been defined, etc. So instead it tries to parse it as a structure field member access, which it's not, and it fails.

If you instead write:

```
UILabel *label = [labels objectAtIndex:1];
label.center.x +=10;
```

Now the compiler knows that `label` is an instance of UILabel, it knows about the property definitions, and it can generate the correct code.

Now you have a second problem, because you are changing a value within a structure. The second line above is shorthand for:

```
label.center.x = label.center.x + 10;
```

This is again shorthand for a Objective-C method call:

```
[label center].x = [label center].x + 10;
```

Because the center point is a CGPoint struct, you have to get/set the entire point value at once, you can't just update the x or y member. So again, you need to do it like this:

```
UILabel *label = [labels objectAtIndex:1];
CGPoint c = label.center;
c.x += 10;
label.center = c;
```

That will do what you want.

If you're tempted to say Objective-C is a stupid language because you need all the temporary variables... well, maybe, but be fair and understand you hit on two special cases in one example.

Comment: also, note that the first object in an array has index 0, so you should say `[labels objectAtIndex:0]`.